# Using Multiple SSH Public Keys

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have a personal account and a company account on Unfuddle.  On Unfuddle SSH keys can only be used on a single account, so I need to create a seperate SSH key on my laptop for both accounts.  I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate two keys with different names (personal is default name and company is {company}_rsa).  The problem now is that it appears that my default key is used everywhere and I can't find out how to specify a key to use in Git for individual repos.

So my question is: How do I specify an SSH key to use on a repo-to-repo basis?

I setup my ssh_config (~/.ssh/config) but it still doesn't seem to work.

config:

```
Host {personalaccount}.unfuddle.com
     HostName {personalaccount}.unfuddle.com
     User git
     IdentityFile /Users/dave/.ssh/id_rsa

Host {companyaccount}.unfuddle.com
     HostName {companyaccount}.unfuddle.com
     User git
     IdentityFile /Users/dave/.ssh/cage_rsa
```

My Git repo config file for a repo on my company unfuddle account looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
     url = git@{companyaccount}.unfuddle.com:{companyaccount}/overall.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

So I am not sure if there is something wrong with my ssh config or my git config.

Comment: Your ssh config looks right, I'm using a similar configuration.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you have an active *ssh-agent* that has your `id_rsa` key loaded, then the problem is likely that *ssh* is offering that key first. Unfuddle probably accepts it for authentication (e.g. in *sshd*) but rejects it for authorization to access the company repositories (e.g. in whatever internal software they use for authorization, possibly something akin to Gitolite). Perhaps there is a way to add your personal key to the company account (multiple people are not sharing the same `corp_rsa` public and private key files, are they?).

---

The `IdentitiesOnly` `.ssh/config` configuration keyword can be used to limit the keys that *ssh* offers to the remote *sshd* to just those specified via `IdentityFile` keywords (i.e. it will refuse to use any additional keys that happen to be loaded into an active *ssh-agent*).

Try these `.ssh/config` sections:

```
Host {personalaccount}.unfuddle.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     IdentitiesOnly yes

Host {companyaccount}.unfuddle.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{companyaccount}_rsa
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then, use Git URLs like these:

```
git@{personalaccount}.unfuddle.com:{personalaccount}/my-stuff.git
git@{companyaccount}.unfuddle.com:{companyaccount}/their-stuff.git
```

---

If you want to take full advantage of the `.ssh/config` mechanism, you can supply your own custom hostname and change the default user name:

```
Host uf-mine
     HostName {personalaccount}.unfuddle.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     IdentitiesOnly yes

Host uf-comp
     HostName {companyaccount}.unfuddle.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{companyaccount}_rsa
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then, use Git URLs like these:

```
uf-mine:{personalaccount}/my-stuff.git
uf-comp:{companyaccount}/their-stuff.git
```

Comment: If you have multiple accounts on the same Unfuddle subdomain (with different SSH keys), you will need to use the second method.

Comment: IdentitiesOnly was essential for me in my gitolite setup, thanks!

Comment: Awesome this fixes the issue that all my keys get sent to github. However, on OS X I have to type in my passphrase everytime.  Is there a way to say only use key specified in config but continue to use ssh agent?

Comment: @Drew: If the key is already loaded into the agent, then the command should still draw it from the agent. Are you sure your key is pre-loaded? Check with `ssh-add -l` before you use your Git host alias. Also the public key file needs to be present so that *ssh* can recognize the key that *ssh-agent* is storing. You can regenerate a lost `.pub` file with a command like `ssh-keygen -f blah -y > blah.pub`.

Comment: Yeah it's in there.  When I removed the IdentitiesOnly call, it sends github 4 different keys (including correct one w/o asking for passphrase).  When I add the call, it only sends the one key but requests the passphrase everytime.  Even when I tell OSX to store the passphrase value in its keychain.

Comment: Adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the very top of one's SSH config file seems to affect all entries and will only try `~/.ssh/id_rsa` if there isn't a matching `Host` entry— which seems to be to probably be the desired behavior for most workstation use-cases.

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly yes`!!! Why is this not true by default since an identity file has been specified?

Comment: Using IdentityFile essentially disables ssh-agent. So you would have to type your passwords and wouldn't be able to use ssh forwarding.

Comment: I meant IdentitiesOnly ^

Answer (score 4):

IdentityFile and IdentitiesOnly work well. What bothers me is having to remember to use different host names to connect to, and the fact that the forwarded agent connection still holds all keys, meaning that if the remote host is compromised, they can use any of my identities while I'm in.

I've recently started using:

https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident

it's a wrapper around ssh, it:

- keeps an entirely separate agent for each identity you define.
- automatically shares agents across login sessions, nothing to do in your .bashrc.
- loads the agent and the corresponding keys on demand the first time you need them.
- determines which agent to use either based on ssh command line (hostname & such) or your current working directory. This is particularly handy as I tend to work from different paths depending on what I am doing.

Answer (score 2):

`man ssh_config`

Something like

```
Host personal_repo
  User personal
  IdentityFile .ssh/personal_rsa

Host company_repo
  User company
  IdentityFile .ssh/company_rsa
```

And use `personal_repo` as host in your git repo.

Comment: Tass, could you review my changes made above?  I added my ssh_config and my git config.

Comment: `Host` is just an identifier - no need for full domain name. That probably creates some hidden bugs. If you change that, you don't need to spell the full name in your git config.

Comment: for gitorious, user = git and host gitorious.org: e.g. git@gitorious.org:~revelut/qt/bruce-sandbox-qt.git   How do you match in your Host a part of the url ? (typically ~revelut for me)

Comment: @Tass so if I give the name company_unfuddle to the SSH config should my URL be git@company_unfuddle:{company}/overall.git?

@Bruce - I am not sure what you are asking.  Could you expand a little more?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proper way if you want to use ssh agent:

```
# Create public keys to make sure they exist
# this is a must if you use ssh agent forwarding
# or want to use ssh-agent at all
ssh-add -L | grep personal > ~/.ssh/personal_identity.pub
ssh-add -L | grep company > ~/.ssh/company_identity.pub


# Add to ~/.ssh/config
Host {personalaccount}.unfuddle.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_identity.pub

Host {companyaccount}.unfuddle.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_identity.pub
```

Explanation: if you have private key in your ~/.ssh directory, ssh-agent won't be used. So we create public key under another name, so that ssh is forced to use ssh-agent. This also helps if you don't have access to private keys (e.g. ssh agent forwarding)

Comment: this might be `ssh-add -L`, not `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I was using ssh-agent forwarding and all the other answers are not relevant when the private key is not on the computer you are running `git push` on.