# SSH and Public Keys

Tags: ssh, public-key

I have created keys for git following instructions on http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

This works nice, but when I try to ssh to another host, it tries to use same public key. Also, ssh to servers without public key, but password authentication fails with

```
$ssh user@host
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

How can I solve this to use default keys for github, but not for other hosts?

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys) but I don't want to add entry for each host, I want other to behave like I don't have any keys configured and ask for password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your GitHub key so that it doesn't use any of the default key files which `ssh` looks for (something like `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github`). Then add the following to `~/.ssh/config` to tell `ssh` to only use this key for connections to GitHub.

```
Host *.github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

All other connections won't attempt key authentication because there aren't default keys. However, there is usually no harm in this happening -- if the key is rejected, `ssh` will attempt password authentication if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

use your `.ssh/config` and the `IdentityFile` expression:

> Specifies a file from which the user's RSA or DSA authentication
>   identity is read. The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol version
>   1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for protocol version 2.
>   Additionally, any identities represented by the authentication agent
>   will be used for authentication.

then refer to `.ssh/id_rsa_github` (or whatever the name of your 'for github only` keypair is')

Comment: Thanks. But when I use -i it does not accept passphrase, and after 3 nonsuccessive attempts I get `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).`. Also, I still don't understand how to force no key to use, but use password auth?