# ssh permission denied public key when adding new key

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I had a id_rsa in ~/.ssh/newfolder/ and using the config file correctly, then I went to add a new one to ~/ssh/git/ and now the git key works but the one in newfolder doesn't. Any help would be aprreciated.

heres a conversation i had with some one i stack overflow of some steps of tried:

> did you added keys into ~/.ssh/config using the scheme: Host your_git_host User git_user_name IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git/git_key Host your_new_host User new_user_name IdentityFile ~/.ssh/newfokder/new_key ? Also, don't forget to set permissions to .ssh and the keys as 700 and 600 correspondingly –  static 10 hours ago
>
> yes i believe that is all correct, is 700 the folder permission? –  user2888676 10 hours ago
>
> yes, the ~/.ssh/ –  static 10 hours ago
>
> yea thats all good... still no progress, i was using the git hub tutorial and i think doing the ssh-add some how screwed it all up, even though removing the keys from within there has no effect –  user2888676 10 hours ago
>
> by removing i mean ssh-add -D –  user2888676 9 hours ago

Comment: found an awnser on this site, http://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys?lq=1 , dont know why I couldnt find it after hours of google